# reading single character in java

Tags: java

```
public class pattern7 {
    public static void main(String args[])
        throws java.io.IOException{

        char c;

        do
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println("\ndo you want more");
            c=(char)System.in.read();
        }while(c=='y');
    }
}
```

the above code should print the * as long as i press 'y' but it does not do so. it let the user to enter choice just once. i know the reason behind this as it uses "enter" as its second value. but i don't know how to make it work. suggest me the code to do the same action properly

Comment: Do you want to skip (ignore) the ENTER or do you want to receive the 'y' without being followed by an ENTER?

Comment: Or you try using Scanner method to get input.

Answer (score 1):

it takes enter key press as a new character. So capture that key press add another read command.

```
    do
    {
        System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println("\ndo you want more");
        do {
            c=(char)System.in.read();
        } while (Character.isWhitespace(c));
    } while (c=='y');
```

Comment: Logically you are correct, The program still terminates after one iteration.  :(

Comment: Ok. For me after two y's the program stops. I am running this on Eclipse.Jdk-7, OS-> windows7

Comment: Read all \r and \n chars, not blindly the next. On some systems you might receive a CR LF, on others only a LF.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'y' character will always be followed by an enter, just always read the full line and check if it only contains the 'y' character:

## Option 1: BufferedReader

You can use `InputStreamReader` in combination with `BufferedReader` to get the full line the user entered. After that, you check that it is not `null` and only contains 'y'.

```
try {
    // Get the object of DataInputStream
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && line.equals("y") ) {
        System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println("\ndo you want more?");
    }
    isr.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

## Option 2: Scanner

The same as above can be achieved by using the [java.util.Scanner](http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner.html) class:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.nextLine(); // reads a line from the console. Can be used instead of br.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Scanner. Here is my code-

```
public class pattern7 {
    public static void main(String args[])
        throws java.io.IOException{

        char c;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        do
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println("\ndo you want more");
            c=reader.next().charAt(0);
        }while(c=='y');
    }
}
```